# How to check if a field has more than one value

Tags: 8, theming

I am working on a field template to display images in a carousel (I'm using BootStrap). My field is named “galerie”
I copied field.html.twig from the core and saved it as field--field-galerie.html.twig
I managed successfuly to add the necessary markup for BootStrap carousel to work.

The wrapping markup displaying the carousel and its control shows up when there is only one image. I thought it would not. It opens after a `{% if multiple %}` condition and closes before the `{% else %}`.
My understanding is that `{% if multiple %}` only checks if the field is set to accept multiple values.

I don't know how to write an condition in twig checking if the field contains one image or more, to trigger (or not) the carousel thingee.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the length filter, which also works on arrays:

```
{% if items|length > 1 %}
  field contains more than 1 item
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thank you, it was exacltly what I needed. I 'm using it right now.